# Refreshing or updating partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have two models. Facilities and Availability. Each facility has many availabilities. On my facilities page, I have a partial that lists out all availabilities for the current facility.

I'm trying to allow CRUD operations on the availabilities. Delete works fine, I do it through ajax and use jquery to delete the row in the table.

I'm having trouble with the create and update. I'm able to do them remotely but reflecting the change without reloading the page has be stumped.

This is what the partial looks [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTopS.png):

```
<tbody class="availabilityContainer">
  <% facility_availabilities?.each do |a|%>
    <tr id="availability_<%= a.id %>">
      <td id="date_<%= a.id %>"><%= a.start_time.strftime("%a, %b %d %Y") %></td>
      <td id="time_<%= a.id %>"><%= a.start_time.strftime("%I:%M  %p") %> - <%= a.end_time.strftime("%I:%M  %p") %></td>
      <td id="price_<%= a.id %>"><%= number_to_currency a.price %></td>
      <td id="discount_<%= a.id %>"><%= number_to_percentage a.discount, precision: 0 %></td>
      <td>
          <!-- Purchase button -->
          <%= link_to("<i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i>".html_safe, "#", class:"btn btn-xs btn-success") %>

          <!-- Edit button -->
          <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editAvailability"><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button> -->
          <%= link_to("<i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>".html_safe, edit_availability_path(a.id) , class:"btn btn-xs btn-primary", data:{toggle:"modal", target:"#editAvailability"}, remote: true) %>

          <!-- Delete button -->
          <%= link_to("<i class='fa fa-times'></i>".html_safe, availability_path(a.id), method: :delete, class:"btn btn-xs btn-danger", remote: true) %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Load Edit Availability Form -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="editAvailability" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"></div>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

I tried some things in js:

```
// Hide modal on update
$("#editAvailability").modal("hide");

// Update view
$("#availability_&lt;%= @availability.id %&gt;").fadeOut(500,function(){
    currentItem = $(this)
  // Get the new object from the database (should just get it from the form but i'm committed now)
  $.get('/availabilities/&lt;%= @availability.id %&gt;', function (data){
    // Append new data to table or refresh partial somehow
  }).done(function() {
      // update the individual row and fade back in?
      $("#availability_&lt;%= @availability.id %&gt;").fadeIn(500)
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've mixed two different approaches and confused because of it. First approach  just append row to a table after pure js request.

```
$.get("ajax_address", function(data){
  $("<tr><td>you new row</td></tr>").appendTo("#table_id");
}
```

You also can chain animation effect to you appendTo, like

```
$("some").appendTo("#table").hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

Second option to do it in more rails way. You just create link with `remote: true` and write your placement logic in you js view (pretty much the same as first solution callback function)

Comment: If every cell `td` has an id, would it be simpler to edit the innerHtml for those cells instead of creating a new row? I ask because each row has a lot of button code I don't want to recreate through jQuery

Comment: I wrote about `create` action. As I understande, you create new row in this case, right?. 

About update - `$("#td_id").html("new content")` should work

Comment: Yea I need both create and update so your answer makes sense sorry. I'm having an issue though, if I do something like this `$("td#date_<%= @availability.id %>").html("<%= @availability.start_time.strftime('%a, %b %d %Y') %>")` I get error: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #availability_&lt;%= @availability.id %&gt;`

Comment: Where have you put your js exactly?

Comment: It's in `availabilites/update.js.erb` It's just that jquery is converting `<` into `&gt` or `&lt`

Comment: I don't think it's jquery. `<%= =>` is erb tags, so they should be replaced before jq even touch the file. Could it be your text editor?

Comment: There was an error in the file. I fixed it. Thanks for the help